# Where is the Cherrypy config file located on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a tool written to be added to the configuration file but I cannot find the file anywhere. Where is the configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no configuration file. All forms of configuration is done through code.**

A simple site-config example using `cheerypy.config`:

```
#cheerypy.config is flat dictionary that you can modify using
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '10.10.10.10',
                        'server.socket_port': 80,
                       })
```

You can get more information [here](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/ConfigAPI)